# alternative to foreignObject for IE9

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, internet-explorer-9, data-visualization

i really like foreignObject to show HTML regions over svg, but today i found out that it doesnt work in IE9 (why am i not surprised)
ok. So i am looking for an alternative that works in IE9, but it seems difficult. The great thing of using foreignObject to display multiple HTML elements.

My D3.js Force layout graph is working great in chrome and FF , but in IE9 it fail because of foreignObject . i add many HTML elements in to Div and also more CSS stuff.
I try to replace foreignObject with other xhtml:div or xhtml:body but it's not working

here is two Fiddles

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/TTKd7/)

need to run on IE9

[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/HCF5W/)

```
node.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "simpleDiv")
    .attr("width",50)
    .attr("overflow", "visible")
    .attr("height", 50)
    .append("xhtml:div").attr("class", "mainDiv").style("cursor", hoverStyle)
    .html(function (d) {
       var htmlString = "";
       var userImage = "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6fN48PEP2-z-JbutdhqfypsYdciYTAZEziHpBJZLAfM6rxqYX";
       htmlString += "<div class='userImage' style='border-color:" + color(d) + "'><image src='" + userImage + "' width='36' height='36'></image></div>";
       htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
       htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
       return htmlString;
     });
```

you can test original example in IE9 also [foreignObject](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make foreignObject work in IE9.
But for your particular task why not just render the user icon and name with `<image>` and `<text>` elements?

Comment: i can do this but problem is server send list of node that having any thing is user,group, or comment chat etc. and for each i have to create custom node in svg so they look different you can watch it in my working fiddle in FF or google chrome. but still i am trying to do it just what you say it's taking time but i have to make run in IE9.