# Issue with SVG in IE9

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have this slider:

http://ftp.escape.pe/slider/

It's working fine in all browsers, except on IE9 (in IE8 it works also).
I'm using SVG in my html code.

Please, can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems foreignObject is broken in IE9.  See here for another person with the same problem:

[alternative to foreignObject for IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950208/alternative-to-foreignobject-for-ie9)

Why are you using foreignObject anyway?

```
<svg>
   <foreignObject style="mask: url(#mask);" height="185px" width="250px">        
      <img src="http://patrickkirkby.com/files/images/gallery/thumb_001.jpg">
   </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

should be able to be replaced with with:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <image xlink:href="http://patrickkirkby.com/files/images/gallery/thumb_001.jpg"
          style="mask: url(#mask)" height="185px" width="250px">
</svg>
```

and this should work in IE.